# Add a comma after each line in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
192.111.139.162:4145
195.144.21.185:1080
198.199.86.11:1080
5.252.161.48:1080
176.9.75.42:1080
31.128.248.2:1080
98.184.33.205:4145
139.59.1.14:1080
154.16.202.22:1080
```

I have a whole pile of proxies (I only showed some, I have hundreds of them), and I made a python script to check if they're valid. But it requires me to put them in a list, like this:

```
'192.111.139.162:4145',
'195.144.21.185:1080',
'198.199.86.11:1080',
'5.252.161.48:1080',
'176.9.75.42:1080',
'31.128.248.2:1080',
'98.184.33.205:4145',
'139.59.1.14:1080',
'154.16.202.22:1080'
```

But I have hundreds of them, and I certainly cannot do it manually. So I need to write a python script to automate it for me.
I searched it everywhere and could not find a solution. Any help?

Comment: `replace('\n', ',\n')`

Comment: Can you help me giving how you have the data, means are these in a list (variable), data set or file? So that i can help with script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't put items into a list the way that you put a `[` in the beginning and a `]` in the end of the text file and adding dozens of commas.

Instead you read the file as it is into a list using Python code:

```
with open("file.txt") as proxyfile:
    lines = proxyfile.readlines()
```

Now you have all the entries in an array called `lines`.

Answer (score 0):

Read the entire file into a string, or read line by line, and use `re.sub` as follows:

```
inp = """192.111.139.162:4145
195.144.21.185:1080
198.199.86.11:1080
5.252.161.48:1080
176.9.75.42:1080
31.128.248.2:1080
98.184.33.205:4145
139.59.1.14:1080
154.16.202.22:1080"""

output = re.sub(r"(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+:\d+)", r"'\1',", inp).rstrip(',')
print(output)
```

This prints:

```
'192.111.139.162:4145',
'195.144.21.185:1080',
'198.199.86.11:1080',
'5.252.161.48:1080',
'176.9.75.42:1080',
'31.128.248.2:1080',
'98.184.33.205:4145',
'139.59.1.14:1080',
'154.16.202.22:1080'
```

Comment: Running the script gives NameError: name 're' is not defined

Comment: @BrandonLi You need `import re` at the top of the script.  Often folks won't add `import` statements to their answers as it might clutter the answer.  Here is a working [demo](https://rextester.com/PTLYS36462) if it interests you.